# How to align slideshow element below header?

Tags: html, css

I'm  trying to fix the slideshow on my site. In the imgur below you can see how the alignment of the slideshow is a few pixels off on both sides. I have been playing with the CSS width trying to fix it, but it remains static. How can I fix this? Any tips? thanks

im trying to make the slideshow the same width of the menu and footer

https://jsfiddle.net/e52ygwez/

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LFav.jpg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>
<head>
<title> Home </title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css"/>

</head>

<div class="container"> 
<div class="logo">
   <h1 align="center">
   <img src="logo2.png" height="110" width="500"  alt="A.Willi A.G" />
</h1>     
</div>

<div class="menu_div"> <!--MENU DIV-->
<ul>
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
   <li><a href="contact.html">Kontakt</a></li>
   <li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Bewerber</a>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="info.html">Info</a>
   <a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a>
</div>  
</li>      

<li class="dropdown"> <!--DRPDWN CLIENTS-->
<a href="#" class="dropbtn">Kunde</a>
<div class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="personnel.html">Personalverleih</a>
   <a href="rental.html">Werkzeuge Mieten</a>
   <a href="refrences.html">Referenzen</a>
   <a href="quali.html">Qulität, Sicherheit und Weiterbildung</a>
</ul>
</li>
</div>

<div class="fadein"> <!--SLIDESHOW-->
   <img src="panorama.jpg">
   <img src="panorama.jpg">
   <img src="panorama.jpg">
</div>
    <p style="text-align:left;">
     Die A.Willi A.G</b> ist als Personalverleiher in der gesamten Schweiz und im Ausland erfolgreich tatig mit über 30-jahrige Erfahrung in dieser Sparte. </p>

<footer class="footer-distributed"> <!--LEFT LOGO FOOT-->
<div class="footer-left"> 
   <img src="awlogoblue.png" height="50" width="250" alt="A.Willi A.G" />   
   <p class="footer-links">     <!--LINKS-->
   <a href="#">Home</a>·
   <a href="#">Zertifikate</a>·
   <a href="#">Datenschutz-Bestimmungen</a>·
   <p class="footer-company-name">&copy;2016 A.Willi A.G</p>
</div>

<div class="footer-center"> <!--CENTER-->
<div>
   <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
   <p><span>Wasgenring 94</span> CH-4055 Basel</p>
</div>
<div>
   <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
   <p>+1 555 123456</p>
</div>
<div>
   <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
   <p>
    </a>
    </p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="footer-right"> <!--RIGHT-->
  <p class="footer-company-about">
  <span>About the company</span>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectateur adispicing elit. Fusce euismod convallis velit, eu auctor lacus vehicula sit amet.
</p>
<div class="footer-icons">
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
</footer>            

</body> 
</div>
</html>
```

> CSS

```
body 

/* font & back clr */

{ font-family: verdana; background:whitesmoke ; color:black; }


.menu_div{ 

background: black; 
width:100%;}


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:table;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.logo {
    height:   
    bottom: 0;
    position: relative;





   } 




li {
    float: left;
}


/* DROPDOWN Txt Color */

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}


/* DROPDOWN Txt BOX Color */


li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #33383b;
}



li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}


/* DROPDOWN content clr */

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 100;
}

/* DROPDOWN TEXT CLR */

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}


/* DROPDOWN COL BOX */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: white}



.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

        @keyframes fade {
        0%   { opacity: 0; }
        11.11%   { opacity: 1; }
        33.33%  { opacity: 1; }
        44.44%  { opacity: 0; }
        100% { opacity: 0; }
}

/* MENU COL */

.menu_div { 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 2.9em;
  margin-bottom: -0.4em;
  margin-top: 0em;
  z-index:1000;

  background-color:#33383b;
}



/* slideshow header */



.fadein { 
position: relative;
    z-index: ;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 3px solid white;
    height: 250px;
    max-width: 100%;
  }

.fadein img{
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}



.fadein img { position:absolute; left:0; right:0; opacity:0; animation-name: fade; animation-duration: 9s; animation-iteration-count: infinite; }
    .fadein img:nth-child(1) { animation-delay: 0s;  }
    .fadein img:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 3s;  }
    .fadein img:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: 6s;  }



/* page container */



.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}



/* article from jobs */


.article {
    text-align: left;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom:11px
}




/* body of text */



textinfo {
width: 300px;
border: 25px solid green;
padding: 25px;
margin: 25px;



/* footer opts */



}

.footer-distributed{
    background-color: #292c2f;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    font: bold 16px sans-serif;

    padding: 30px 30px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-left,
.footer-distributed .footer-center,
.footer-distributed .footer-right{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

/* footer left */

.footer-distributed .footer-left{
    width: 40%;
}

/* the company logo */

.footer-distributed h3{
    color:  #ffffff;
    font: normal 36px 'Cookie', cursive;
    margin: 0;
}

.footer-distributed h3 span{
    color:  #5383d3;
}

/* footer links */

.footer-distributed .footer-links{
    color:  #ffffff;
    margin: 20px 0 12px;
    padding: 0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-links a{
    display:inline-block;
    line-height: 1.8;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:  inherit;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-name{
    color:  #8f9296;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
}

/* footer center */

.footer-distributed .footer-center{
    width: 35%;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center i{
    background-color:  #33383b;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 42px;
    margin: 10px 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center i.fa-envelope{
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 38px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ffffff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin:0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p span{
    display:block;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:2;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p a{
    color:  #5383d3;
    text-decoration: none;;
}


/* footer right */

.footer-distributed .footer-right{
    width: 20%;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-about{
    line-height: 20px;
    color:  #92999f;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-about span{
    display: block;
    color:  #ffffff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-icons{
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-icons a{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color:  #33383b;
    border-radius: 2px;

    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;

    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

/* un responsive rmoval */

@media (max-width: 880px) {

    .footer-distributed{
        font: bold 14px sans-serif;
    }

    .footer-distributed .footer-left,
    .footer-distributed .footer-center,
    .footer-distributed .footer-right{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .footer-distributed .footer-center i{
        margin-left: 0;
    }


logo {

margin-bottom:100px;

     }
```

Comment: Not quite sure if this works because of the jsfiddle not loading your local pictures, but your header (.fadein, i believe) is not closed. This might be the issue, but it could also be that your slideshow pictures are not as big as .container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's being caused by your border from the `.fadein` class. Remove line 131 from your jsfiddle.

Comment: No problem! I was able to quick find the issue with the chrome inspector. Something to look into when you have time! Also, I sometimes I put different color borders in to see where the problem might be.

Answer (score 1):

How to align slideshow element below header. Well I didn't found an element named header. Anyway if you want an element to be above other elements you need to set `z-index` to that element.

Something like:

```
header{
   z-index:100;
}

.all other elements to be below{
   z-index:1;  // As long as an element z-index is below 100 or not set header stays on the top
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: It is called .fadein, for reference. The guy is asking how to fix the misalignment of the picture and the header above it, not the z-index.